# Is it possible to use two fonts in TextButtonStyle in LibGDX using JSON?

Tags: android, json, button, libgdx, scene2d

I want to use JSON to set up my button in LibGDX. I have two fonts (carterone_red.fnt, carterone_green.fnt). When the button is down, it use carterone_red font and when the button is up, it turns carterone_green.fnt. Is it possible?

The following code is not working.

Thanks,
Vincent

```
 {
    com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont:{
    carterone-font: { file: fonts/carterone_green.fnt }
    carterone-font2: { file: fonts/carterone_red.fnt }
    },
    com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color: {
        green: { a: 1, b: 0, g: 1, r: 0 },
        white: { a: 1, b: 1, g: 1, r: 1 },
        red: { a: 1, b: 0, g: 0, r: 1 },
        black: { a: 1, b: 0, g: 0, r: 0 }
    },
    com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton$TextButtonStyle: {
        carterone: { down: button2,font: carterone2-font, up: button1, font: carterone-font, fontColor: white }  
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question right then you want your button to be in green font if it is up and in red font if it is down.
Then the easiest approach I see is:

1. create one BitmapFont, which should be your "carterone" font, but in **white** (!) color
2. then in your skin json file you can set the attributes `fontColor` & `downFontColor` to set red & green color accordingly.

==> in the end your skin.json will look more or less like this:

```
{
com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont:{
    carterone-font: { file: fonts/carterone_white.fnt }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color: {
    green: { a: 1, b: 0, g: 1, r: 0 },
    white: { a: 1, b: 1, g: 1, r: 1 },
    red: { a: 1, b: 0, g: 0, r: 1 },
    black: { a: 1, b: 0, g: 0, r: 0 }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton$TextButtonStyle: {
    carterone: { down: button2, up: button1, fontColor: green, downFontColor: red }  
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The attribute to set your font family is:

```
android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
```

If this is a custom font, place it in the following directory (assets, raw doesn't work):

```
assets/fonts
```